# Can't scan dataframe with usual command due to formatting issues

Tags: r

I typically read in excel files with `col_types = 'text'` using `read_excel` because it makes scanning the data easier - but a problem I'm having right now is that I need to keep the data in its original format so I can preserve my dttmcolumns as dates and not excel date codes.
Typically, I run a scan for text like `colSums(as.character(ing1 == 'STKMA'))` looking to return the number of occurrence in each column which works fine when all columns are chrformat. I get the error:

```
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

How do I accomplish my tasks around this like the above character search I usually perform? Thanks you (edited)

Comment: There is a typo in your example code `as.character(ing1 == 'STKMA')` should be `as.character(ing1) == "STKMA"`.  Also if it is a single column/vector, then `colSums` wouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check that the date variables are in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`